# Custom sort with 3 keys

Tags: vba, excel

I have a range which I am trying to custom sort with 3 keys.
I am trying to construct two string arrays from two different columns on a sheet and use these to create two custom lists which I can sort with - the third key just sorting via a standard key.

However, I cannot get the range to sort in the exact order of my customer lists and I believe it is just sorting ascending.

Here is my code below:

```
Sub SortIntoTeams()
Dim LastRow As Long, LastColumn As Long, FormattedRange As Range
LastRow = Sheets(1).Range("B65536").End(xlUp).Row
LastColumn = Sheets(1).Cells(1, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
Set FormattedRange = Sheets(1).Range(Cells(8, 1), Cells(LastRow, LastColumn))

Dim SortKey1 As Range, SortKey2 As Range, SortKey3 As Range
Set SortKey1 = Sheets(1).Cells(7, 1)
Set SortKey2 = Sheets(1).Cells(7, 10)
Set SortKey3 = Sheets(1).Cells(7, 3)

Dim sCustomList1() As String, sCustomList2() As String
Dim x As Long, i As Long
ReDim sCustomList1(1 To Sheets(1).Range("A65536").End(xlUp).Row)
ReDim sCustomList2(1 To Sheets(1).Range("E65536").End(xlUp).Row)

For x = 1 To Sheets(1).Range("A65536").End(xlUp).Row
    sCustomList1(x) = Sheets(2).Cells(x, 1)
Next x
For i = 1 To Sheets(1).Range("E65536").End(xlUp).Row
    sCustomList2(i) = Sheets(2).Cells(i, 5)
Next i

Application.AddCustomList ListArray:=sCustomList1
Application.AddCustomList ListArray:=sCustomList2

Sheets(1).Sort.SortFields.Clear
FormattedRange.Sort Key1:=SortKey1, Order1:=xlAscending, Key2:=SortKey2, Order2:=xlAscending, Key3:=SortKey3, Order3:=xlAscending, Header:=xlGuess, _
    OrderCustom:=Application.CustomListCount + 1, MatchCase:=False, _
    Orientation:=xlTopToBottom, DataOption1:=xlSortNormal

Application.DeleteCustomList Application.CustomListCount

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

I have noticed two things that may help here.

Rewrite the sections obtaining the last row to be used like this:
    Sheets(1).Cells(rows.count,1).end(xlup).row  ' this would be for column A.
    Sheets(1).cells(rows.count,2).end(xlup).row  ' this would be for column B.

You would use rows.count,5 for those in Column E.

Also, it appears you need to indicate a sort method, such as:  sortmethod:=xlpinyin